# Using Application.OnTime, trouble calling sub

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do a task repeatedly, using Application.OnTime, but can't get it to run my Sub. Here's a small example:

```
Sub HelloWorld()
Cells(1, 1) = Time
End Sub

Sub ThisWorks()
Application.OnTime Now, "HelloWorld"
End Sub
```

When I try to run this, I get "Cannot run Macro !Bok1HelloWorld, Macro may not be available, or all macros may be deactivated" (Roughly translated from Norwegian).

If I replace `Application.OnTime` with `Application.Run`, it prints the time as it should.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message seems quite descriptive. There is nothing wrong with this code (although you might remove Application.OnTime, as far as it is called right away and thus can be replaced with a mere call to this function).

Comment: My goal is to set it to Now + 2 seconds, and call itself. Perhaps I should have it calling itself in the MWE as well, I just tried a lot of different variations, to troubleshoot.

Comment: Your error message says that it does not matter what you try because the code will never be reached. Why not creating a new Excel file, putting this code in Workbook_Open for example and confirming that it works fine? Then you can figure out why the code in your original code is not being accessed.

Comment: Where are the `Sub`s stored in? At least the Sub HelloWorld should be within a `Module` not within the `ThisWorkbook` class module.

Comment: I have been making click buttons and manipulating the code that pops up with "view code".

Comment: It works in the module! :D Thanks a lot!

Do you have a link to a guide on how to organize VBA code? Or does it suffice to simply put it all in modules?